# Regular expression match in any order

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying code a program to recognize what hand you have while playing poker.  The pattern object i'm creating is in the format to check for five cards, with each card defined by the value and then the suit.  So for example, ace of spades would be denoted as As.  I have the following code to recognize a straight, but it only works if it's in order.  How would I make it recognize a string like `5d4sAc3s2h` as a straight?  Thanks for any help!

```
Pattern[] floppedStraightCheck;
floppedStraightCheck = new Pattern[10];
floppedStraightCheck[0] = Pattern.compile("(([aA][scdhSCDH])([2][scdhSCDH])([3][scdhSCDH])([4][scdhSCDH])([5][scdhSCDH])");
```

Comment: Honestly, it doesn't sound like regular expressions are the best solution for this problem. Parse the string first (regex might help with this, but it should be simple enough to do without regex) to create an array of `CardInfo` objects (or similar), then analyze that array to see if it's a straight, full house, etc.

Comment: Yes, and a string may not be the best way to represent a hand

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to put your core application logic in one regex. You should write methods instead which will be a lot more readable and maintainable.

Comment: thank you all for the help.  as you can probably tell, i'm still very green and trying to understand which tool serves me best in what situation.  this is all very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I have to precisely agree with the comments posted above. I do not think that a `regular expression` is the appropriate way to compose this. I would also advise that you use a different approach of a hand than a string. The important thing you can learn about regular expressions in this case, is when `not` to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Not really good task for regex. You have multiple `and` conditions and you can use positive lookahead for that.

```
^(?=.*[aA][scdhSCDH])(?=.*2[scdhSCDH])(?=.*3[scdhSCDH])(?=.*4[scdhSCDH])(?=.*5[scdhSCDH]).{10}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/i_xO4J3FWW_LRDWG)

Shorter version would be:

```
^(?=(..)*[aA])(?=(..)*2)(?=(..)*3)(?=(..)*4)(?=(..)*5)(.[scdhSCDH]){5}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/mH8EibudWw7UiA28)